# Extract number from a website using beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use urllib to grab a html page, then use beautifulsoup to extract data out. I want to get all the number from comments_42.html and print out the sum of them, then display the numbers of data. 
Here is my code, I am trying to use regex, but it doesn't work for me.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    print tag
```

Comment: 1. You're not using regex as far as I can see; 2. What precisely does *"doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: I mean I got stack when I am using regex, it may caused by my low skill on coding.

Comment: So? This isn't a tutorial service. *Make an attempt.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use findAll() method of BeautifulSoup to extract all span tags with class 'comments', since they contain the information you need. You can then perform any operation on them depending on your requirements.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
data = soup.findAll("span", { "class":"comments" })
numbers = [d.text for d in data]
```

Here is the output:

```
[u'100', u'97', u'87', u'86', u'86', u'78', u'75', u'74', u'72', u'72',   u'72', u'70', u'70', u'66', u'66', u'65', u'65', u'63', u'61', u'60', u'60', u'59', u'59', u'57', u'56', u'54', u'52', u'52', u'51', u'47', u'47', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'38', u'35', u'32', u'31', u'24', u'19', u'19', u'18', u'17', u'16', u'13', u'8', u'7', u'1', u'1', u'1']
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works very well for me, is there any way t o get rid of "u' '"? Sry for reply so late, I need use vpn to connect website to go through GFW, that's why I couldn't reply ASAP.

Comment: Use `numbers = [d.text.encode('utf-8') for d in data]`

Answer (score 2):

I am taking the same course from Coursera as you are. Instead of going for the above solutions, do you mind trying this one. I feel this one is within the scope of what we had learnt till the above mentioned problem. It absolutely worked for me.

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import *

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_216543.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
sum=0
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    y=str(tag)
    x= re.findall("[0-9]+",y)
    for i in x:
        i=int(i)
        sum=sum+i
print sum
```

Comment: Is it not better to do `x = re.findall("\d+", y)`? Then you can skip the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

@Learner's solution is completely right ! but if you want to do more with names and comments , you can do this which returns list of names and comments :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib
url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
all  = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'comments'},text=re.compile(r'[0-9]{0,4}')) #use regex to extract only numbers
cleaned = filter(lambda x: x!=u'\n',all)[4:]
In [18]: cleaned
Out[18]: 
[u'Leven',
 u'100',
 u'Mahdiya',
 u'97',
 u'Ajayraj',
 u'87',
 u'Lillian',
 u'86',
 u'Aon',
 u'86',
 u'Ruaraidh',
 u'78',
 u'Gursees',
 u'75',
 u'Emmanuel',
 u'74',
 u'Christy',
 u'72',
 u'Annoushka',
 u'72',
 u'Inara',
 u'72',
 u'Caite',
 u'70',
 u'Rosangel',
 u'70',
 u'Iana',
 u'66',
 u'Anise',
 u'66',
 u'Jaosha',
 u'65',
 u'Cadyn',
 u'65',
 u'Edward',
 u'63',
 u'Charlotte',
 u'61',
 u'Sammy',
 u'60',
 u'Zarran',
 u'60',.....] #
```

Comment: That's amazing!! And you used regex, which is exactly i want, but how could i get away " u" in the list? btw sry for reply so late, there is two internet in the world, China and others, it;s hard for me to use vpn to check answer all the time.

Comment: @Saikorin : u shows it's a unicode string! you can use ** encode() ** method to convert it to normal string. for example if  ustr = u'str'  which is unicode , str = ustr.encode() is a normal string.

Comment: I got it, but i still a little bit confuse about unicode output in python, gonna check it out. Thank you and Learner, 100% solved all my confuses!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you have to import regular expressions in order to use them in the code.

import re

Answer (score 0):

Do it the basic way…

```
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
sum = 0
count = 0
for tag in tags:
# Look at the parts of a tag

    #print tag.contents[0]
    num = float(tag.contents[0])
    #print num
    sum = sum + num
    count = count + 1

print 'count:',count   
print 'sum:',sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this on curser and it gave me all the right answers. Hope it helps ;)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
sum = 0
count = 0
for tag in tags:
# Look at the parts of a tag

    #print tag.contents[0]
    num = float(tag.contents[0])
    #print num
    sum = sum + num
    count = count + 1

print ('count:', count)  
print ('sum:', sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re
lst = list()
sum = 0

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    strtag = str(tag)
    lst = re.findall('[0-9+]+',strtag)
    sum = sum + int(lst[0])
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

### I just mixed the top two solutions and created a general solution.

### Have a look at it

---

```
import urllib.request
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('Enter: ')
tag = input("input the html tag to search: ")
parameter = input("Enter the html  parameter of the tag for better selection (optional): ")
p_value = input("Enter the parameter value (optional): ")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
if not parameter == "" and not p_value == "":
    numbers = soup(tag, {parameter: p_value})
else:
    numbers = soup(tag)
sumation = 0
for number in numbers:
    n = str(number)
    x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', n)
    for item in x:
        sumation += int(item)
print(sumation)
```

---

#### It will take the html address, html tag to search and two optional inputs to more narrow down the search.

- `Tag` takes the html tag to search as input
- `Parameter` takes html parameters like `class`, `id` etc.
- `p_value` takes the class name or the id name as input

Answer (score -1):

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error

import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('Enter - ')


html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

tags=soup('span')

sum=0

for tag in tags:

    x=re.findall("[0-9]+",tag)



    for i in x:

        z=int(i)


        sum=sum+i


print(sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to format the code as well as adding explanation as to what you code does and why OP should use it or is a better solution then the accepted answer.